# How can I get commit message on file using nodegit?

Tags: git, nodegit

Currently, I am listing the files on git tree using:

```
repository
    .getBranchCommit(treeRefName)
    .then((commit)=> commit.getTree())
    .then((tree) => {
        obj.repositoryTree = tree;
        obj.repositoryTreeEntries = tree.entries();
        fullfill(obj);
    })
    .catch(reject);
```

And further listing out `OID` using [oid](http://www.nodegit.org/api/tree_entry/#oid) method. Further trying to get commit message using:

```
Git.Commit
    .lookup(repository, oid)
    .then((commit) => {
        console.log(commit.message());
    })
    .then(() => fullfill(obj))
    .catch(reject);
```

As mentioned in [lookup](http://www.nodegit.org/api/commit/#lookup) method. The problem is that it kept crashing. Further on a simple `git log` from terminal revealed that the `oid` was not the same as commit hash. Where exactly am I going wrong with this, to fetch the last commit that changed the file?

Comment: Could you attach the equivalent of what you want to do with the Git command line to clearly identify and understand what your use case and desired end goal is?

Answer (score 0):

`RevWalk`'s `fileHistoryWalk` function is supposed to help you achieve this but it's rather counterintuitive.

See [nodegit/nodegit#1068](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1068) and [nodegit/nodegit#1174](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1174)